# How to serve a web request using hbase

Tags: web-services, hadoop, web, hbase

I have about 3 million documents that are pdfs, docs and images. I have build a website and if user search from website interface, I have to serve those hbase stored documents as required.

> How can I do it?
>
> Is it good to use hbase for serving web documents (in future these
>   documents will be further increased) ?

My hadoop version is 1.2.1 and hbase 0.94.

Comment: what hbase gives you over a regular filesystem in your use case? For sure it is slower, requires more disk space, set up, etc, etc.

Comment: Can regular filesystem can handle such big ammount of files ?

Comment: yes. search servers can handle more than this in a scalable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer in this case to have a search server that index this data and the web will integrate with this search server api for example: Solr, is an open source search server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we index images in solr and can be retrieved  from solr?

Comment: Solr is a search product that can index any document type including images.

Comment: Can you provide me some link or reference to some solr example like my case ?

Comment: This is the Apache Solr ref on how to configure and index content in Solr: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Indexing+and+Basic+Data+Operations . This reference is very useful to get started and setup solr and configure it, and ingest data and all the way to advanced settings. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, if you have scanned images that has text, this reference helps you step by step how to configure Solr to extract text within images. https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/indexing-and-searching-text-within-images-with-apache-solr/  -- Hope this helps.